# Android application getting crashed when try to Implement facebook login?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm implementing Facebook login to my android app..

but when i run the app, im getting porblem..

here is the **Logcat**..

```
12-07 16:04:51.687    3556-3556/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.administrator.mosbeau, PID: 3556
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:436)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2245)
            at com.example.administrator.mosbeau.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:60)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
     Caused by: null
            at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:99)
            at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.getCallbackRequestCodeOffset(FacebookSdk.java:735)
            at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl$RequestCodeOffset.toRequestCode(CallbackManagerImpl.java:109)
            at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.<clinit>(LoginButton.java:58)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:436)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2245)
            at com.example.administrator.mosbeau.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:60)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

here is my activity

**LoginActivity.java**

```
package com.example.administrator.mosbeau;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

import org.json.JSONObject;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btnSignin;
    EditText txtEmail, txtPassword;
    TextView txtSignup, txtForgot;

    UserLocalStore userLocalStore;

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private Button btnLoginfb;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    FbUser FbUser;


    String Expn =
            "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
                    +"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                    +"[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
                    +"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                    +"[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
                    +"([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        //boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
        if(isConnected){

        }else{
            nointernet();
        }

        txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
        btnSignin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnSignin.setOnClickListener(this);
        txtSignup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textSignup);
        txtSignup.setOnClickListener(this);
        txtForgot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textForgot);
        txtForgot.setOnClickListener(this);

        userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnSubmit:
                String customers_email_address = txtEmail.getText().toString();
                String customers_password = txtPassword.getText().toString();

                if(customers_email_address.length()==0){
                    txtEmail.setError("Email Address is required.");
                }
                else if(customers_email_address.length()<=4){
                    txtEmail.setError("Email Address must be at least 5 characters long.");
                }
                else if(customers_email_address.matches(Expn)){
                    if(customers_password.length()==0){
                        txtPassword.setError("Password is required.");
                    }
                    else if(customers_password.length()<=6){
                        txtPassword.setError("Your Password must contain a minimum of 7 characters!");
                    }
                    else {
                        User user = new User(customers_email_address, customers_password);
                        authenticate(user);
                    }
                }else{
                    txtEmail.setError("Email Address is not valid.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.textSignup:
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.textForgot:
                Intent myForgotIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ForgotPasswordActivity.class);
                startActivity(myForgotIntent);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void authenticate(User user){
        ServerRequests serverRequests = new ServerRequests(this);
        serverRequests.fetchUSerDataInBackground(user, new GetUSerCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void done(User returnedUser) {
                if (returnedUser == null) {
                    showErrorMessage();
                } else {
                    logUserIn(returnedUser);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void showErrorMessage(){
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        //dialogBuilder.setTitle("Oops!");
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("Please check your email or password.");
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.show();
        TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        dialog.show();
    }

    private void logUserIn(User returnedUser) {
        userLocalStore.storeUserData(returnedUser);
        userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(true);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


        callbackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        loginButton= (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email", "user_friends");

        btnLoginfb= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginfb);
        btnLoginfb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();

                loginButton.performClick();

                loginButton.setPressed(true);

                loginButton.invalidate();

                loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, mCallBack);

                loginButton.setPressed(false);

                loginButton.invalidate();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallBack = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();

            // App code
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {

                            Log.e("response: ", response + "");
                            try {
                                FbUser = new FbUser();
                                FbUser.facebookID = object.getString("id").toString();
                                FbUser.email = object.getString("email").toString();
                                FbUser.name = object.getString("name").toString();
                                FbUser.gender = object.getString("gender").toString();
                                PrefUtils.setCurrentUser(FbUser,LoginActivity.this);

                            }catch (Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"welcome "+FbUser.name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,LogoutActivity.class);
                            //startActivity(intent);
                            //finish();

                        }

                    });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };

    public void nointernet(){
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("There seems to be a problem with your connection.");
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Edit Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Stop the activity
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
            }

        });
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Reload", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Stop the activity
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
        AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.show();
        TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

im getting problem in this part..

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
```

i add this code

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

here

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

and im now getting this error

```
12-07 16:22:09.077    5663-5663/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Service com.facebook.mqttlite.MqttService has leaked IntentReceiver com.facebook.rti.mqtt.e.h@4910f74 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.facebook.mqttlite.MqttService has leaked IntentReceiver com.facebook.rti.mqtt.e.h@4910f74 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:968)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:769)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1827)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1807)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:503)
            at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.e.f.a(KeepaliveManager.java:170)
            at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.f.i.<init>(MqttConnectionManager.java:193)
            at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.f.an.a(MqttPushServiceBootstrap.java:473)
            at com.facebook.rti.push.service.r.a(FbnsServiceBootstrap.java:64)
            at com.facebook.mqttlite.MqttService.f(MqttService.java:473)
            at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.f.af.c(MqttPushService.java:211)
            at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.f.g.a(MqttBackgroundService.java:145)
            at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.f.h.handleMessage(MqttBackgroundService.java:46)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
12-07 16:22:09.087    5663-5663/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Service com.facebook.mqttlite.MqttService has leaked IntentReceiver com.facebook.rti.mqtt.common.b.e@2d334e2d that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.facebook.mqttlite.MqttService has leaked IntentReceiver com.facebook.rti.mqtt.common.b.e@2d334e2d that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:968)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:769)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1827)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1807)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1801)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:496)
            at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.common.b.d.j(MqttNetworkManager.java:67)
            at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.common.b.d.<init>(MqttNetworkManager.java:54)
            at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.f.an.a(MqttPushServiceBootstrap.java:174)
            at com.facebook.rti.push.service.r.a(FbnsServiceBootstrap.java:64)
            at com.facebook.mqttlite.MqttService.f(MqttService.java:473)
            at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.f.af.c(MqttPushService.java:211)
            at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.f.g.a(MqttBackgroundService.java:145)
            at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.f.h.handleMessage(MqttBackgroundService.java:46)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
12-07 16:22:09.087    5663-5886/? W/msgr(:<default>):QuickExperimentControllerImpl﹕ Exposure of experiment com.facebook.widget.tiles.annotations.c@2487e599 occurred when no user was logged in
12-07 16:22:09.087    5663-5663/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Service com.facebook.mqttlite.MqttService has leaked IntentReceiver com.facebook.rti.mqtt.common.d.t@315780dc that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.facebook.mqttlite.MqttService has leaked IntentReceiver com.facebook.rti.mqtt.common.d.t@315780dc that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:968)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:769)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1827)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1807)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:503)
            at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.common.d.s.<init>(WakingExecutorService.java:90)
            at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.f.an.a(MqttPushServiceBootstrap.java:304)
            at com.facebook.rti.push.service.r.a(FbnsServiceBootstrap.java:64)
            at com.facebook.mqttlite.MqttService.f(MqttService.java:473)
            at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.f.af.c(MqttPushService.java:211)
            at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.f.g.a(MqttBackgroundService.java:145)
            at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.f.h.handleMessage(MqttBackgroundService.java:46)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

here is my activity_login

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:fillViewport="false">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:minHeight="615dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/logolock"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ff6d6e71"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size17"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txtPassword"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtEmail"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:textColor="#ff6d6e71"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size17"
            android:hint="Password"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sign in"
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:textColor="#ff6d6e71"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtPassword"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size17"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_buttonpink" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Forgot your Password ?"
            android:id="@+id/textForgot"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnSubmit"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnSubmit"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ff607d8b"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size17"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:id="@+id/textSignup"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textForgot"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnSubmit"
            android:textColor="#ff607d8b"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size17"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login with facebook"
            android:id="@+id/btnLoginfb"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textForgot"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_buttonblue"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size17"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

        <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Help"
            android:id="@+id/btnLoginhelp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnLoginfb"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnLoginfb"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_buttonpink"
            android:textColor="#ff6d6e71"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size17"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:ems="6"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Skip"
            android:id="@+id/btnLoginskip"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_buttonpink"
            android:textColor="#ff6d6e71"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnLoginhelp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnLoginfb"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size17"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:ems="6"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

i have main activity when i click login button it will go to loginactivity..

here is the mainactivity code..

```
package com.example.administrator.mosbeau;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

public class IndexActivity extends Activity {

    Button joinbutton, signbutton;
    UserLocalStore userLocalStore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        //boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
        if(isConnected){

        }else{
            nointernet();
        }


        userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);

        // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
        joinbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.joinbutton);
        signbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signbutton);

        // Capture button clicks
        joinbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Start NewActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(IndexActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        signbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Start NewActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(IndexActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(authenticate() == true){
            /*Intent myIntent = new Intent(IndexActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);*/
            displayUserDetails();
        }
    }

    private boolean authenticate() {
        if (userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void displayUserDetails(){
        User user = userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser();

        if(user.customers_id==""){
        }else{
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(IndexActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }

    public void nointernet(){
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("There seems to be a problem with your connection.");
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Edit Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Stop the activity
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
            }

        });
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Reload", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Stop the activity
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
        AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.show();
        TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

please help me..

thanks

joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the SDK in `oncreate` after `setContentView` as follows and remove the entire code from `onResume`

```
/*Init Facebook SDK */
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
```

You can try with the following method after Initialize the SDK for logging without using Facebook login button, doesn't required to call it's `performClick()` in another button click.

```
// Facebook user data access permissions
private final String PERMISSIONS[] = new String[]{"public_profile", "user_birthday", "email"};

    /**
     * Login to app with Facebook account
     */
    private void doFacebookLogin() {
    //Initialize mCallbackManager 
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList(PERMISSIONS));
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // Login success, now request for user details
                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(
                                            JSONObject object,
                                            GraphResponse response) {

                                        if (response.getError() != null) {
                                            // failed to fetch user details

                                        } else {
                                            // Successfully retrieved user details
                                            String email, firstName, gender, birthday;

                                            try {
                                                if (object.has("email")) {
                                                    email = object.getString("email");

                                                }
                                                if (object.has("first_name")) {
                                                    firstName = object.getString("first_name");

                                                }
                                                if (object.has("gender")) {
                                                    gender = object.getString("gender");

                                                }
                                                if (object.has("birthday")) {
                                                    birthday = object.getString("birthday");

                                                }



                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                // failed to parse facebook response

                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", "email,first_name,gender,birthday");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        request.executeAsync();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                      // App code
                    }
                });
    }
```

And don't forget to keep below snippet in your manifest

```
<activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

<meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

Remove the `com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton` from XML unless you need it.

Comment: What is `MqttService` ?

Comment: Have you registering any services and leave it without unregistering in previous activity ?

Comment: i have main activity when i click login button it will go to loginactivity.. please see edit..

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your `OnCreateView` of `LoginActivity`

```
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

and let me know it is working or not

Comment: post your `activity_login` xml file